# Can I display an embedded visualforce page on record create?

Tags: visualforce, lightning, page-layout

If I have a visualforce page embedded on my custom object's standard page layout, should it show when I create a new record or only on edit?

I created a basic form for some questions where I needed a longer label than what the field label allows, but it's only showing on edit and not when I create a new record. I'm using lightning experience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Visualforce cannot be embedded in that way. (See this old [IdeaExchange post](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br8CAAS), which essentially declines to  implement that use case in favor of unspecified alternatives).

Instead, you'd need to override the New action with a Visualforce page or Lightning component that completely replaces the native page layout, which is a little heavyweight for many applications. You might consider instead whether a Record Create Quick Action or a Flow could help address your needs in terms of a more interactive record create experience.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of, but I saw another post here where the user indicated inline VF was rolled out with "new" in lightning, but I think that's only in edit. Definitely don't want to do a whole new record VF page, so maybe a flow is the way to go.