# Inline VF page does not appear during Record creation

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, page-layout

I have created an inline VF page and added to the page layout. Inline VF page display correctly when Record is in View or Edit mode. But when I try to create a record, inline VF page does not appear.

Is this a known issue? If yes, Can someone please share the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is answered here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/252338/10073

I cannot find source docs for this, but this is still the case as of January 2021 based on my tests

Comment: I referred this link earlier but the Ideaexchange link which is mentioned there talked about Inline VF issue during Record Edit not on Record Create.

Comment: Its unclear in the docs as of Jan.’21, unfortunately. If you find any docs or ideas mentioning support for inline/embedded vfps in standard “create” pages please share or upvote. (Its unusual that we get it in edit but not create (and only in lightning/LEX edit , not in classic edit due to limited scope delivery of https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br8CAAS).  Afterall, button overrides support both new and edit, so its a surprise that embedded vfp appears in lex edit but not classic edit, and not standard create/creation pages)

Comment: I have already raised a case with Salesforce. I will update here once Salesforce share something with me.

Comment: Confirmed with Salesforce and they said this is expected behavior on Record Create. They asked me to post an idea which I have already created. Please vote my idea. https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000cifYQAQ